# MTU setting not working as expected

Tags: networking, server

Ubuntu 20 /etc/network/interfaces is set and server boots.
While we can connect in, getting out is not possible.  When
the MTU is updated to 1500 vs 9000, everything works as
expected.

We checked another server that is working.  For some reason,
there are duplicate routes.  One is set for onlink and the other
for static.  The server that has issues only shows onlink;
however, static is set in interfaces.

We thought that is might be MTU PATH DISCOVERY
overriding the MTU; however, I do not see where
that could be set.  We already looked in /proc.

While we have not checked the switch, we are running out
of ideas.

Thoughts/comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such product, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 Server?   (the *year* format signifies different products to the far more widely used *year.month* products; ie. specialist server products for use in devices, appliances or the cloud).

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated in Ubuntu 20.xx in favor of netplan. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.